# Bottom fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want the navigation bar to be at the bottom of the page, which I've been able to do just fine, but I think I picked a pretty bad method for orienting the position of the links. The problem with the way I've done it using absolute positioning is when I shrink the screen, it cuts everything off without a scroll bar. If I use float, I'm not sure how to use the image replacement trick for the 1st link.

Ideally, it should keep everything centered until the window is too small and then allow the user to scroll side to side to see whatever was cut off. I'm sure there is an easy fix to this but I'm having trouble finding any information on link positioning for a bottom fixed menu with image replacement. I appreciate the help.

Here is my code:

```css
li#initials{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(../images/initials.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

/*makes initials img clickable*/
#initials a{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
}

li#story {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 300px;
}
li#gallery {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 400px;
}
li#party {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 500px;
}
li#event {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 650px;
}
li#travel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 750px;
}
li#rsvp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 850px;
}
li#gifts {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 950px;
}
li#print {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 1050px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="page-menu">
    <ul id="bottom-nav">
        <li id="initials"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="story"><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
        <li id="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="party"><a href="party.html">Wedding Party</a></li>
        <li id="event"><a href="event.html">Event</a></li>
        <li id="travel"><a href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
        <li id="rsvp"><a href="rsvp.html">RSVP</a></li>
        <li id="gifts"><a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a></li>
        <li id="print"><a href="images/invitation.pdf">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: use fixed instead of absolute and your way of positioning is also not good

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'll have more time to work on this after Christmas. Hopefully it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

use fixed instead of absolute and your way of positioning is also not efficient

```css
 #page-menu{ position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:15%;}

#page-menu li{ display:inline-block; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<nav id="page-menu">
    <ul id="bottom-nav">
        <li id="initials"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="story"><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
        <li id="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="party"><a href="party.html">Wedding Party</a></li>
        <li id="event"><a href="event.html">Event</a></li>
        <li id="travel"><a href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
        <li id="rsvp"><a href="rsvp.html">RSVP</a></li>
        <li id="gifts"><a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a></li>
        <li id="print"><a href="images/invitation.pdf">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code retains menu in the center at all times.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/qsu3q3q6/1/

```
<nav>
<div id="page-menu">
    <ul id="bottom-nav">
        <li id="initials"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="story"><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
        <li id="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="party"><a href="party.html">Wedding Party</a></li>
        <li id="event"><a href="event.html">Event</a></li>
        <li id="travel"><a href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
        <li id="rsvp"><a href="rsvp.html">RSVP</a></li>
        <li id="gifts"><a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a></li>
        <li id="print"><a href="images/invitation.pdf">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>

nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:#666;
    width:100%;
}
#page-menu {
    width: 80%; //whatever you width is
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#f00;
    text-align:center; //remove this if you want
}

#bottom-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
}
```